# html css - why is this place becoming insivible in mobile phones

Tags: html, css

I have this page: http://www.places4two.de/. the login scope in the top part of page is disappearing if i open the page in mobile devices. In normal webpages, they are visible.

why is this happening?

I tried with:

```
z-index: 1000;position: relative;
```

but still insivible.

Comment: It does the same thing when you open it in a desktop browser and resize the window to a smaller size (tried with Firefox)...

Comment: Do you have a CSS media query or JS that's hiding it at a certain width?  It looks like your right ad disappears at the same time... try resizing your browser until it appears/disappears and watch the behavior of the ad.

Comment: @AdamPlocher, oh, i think, this the responsiveness of the nav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learn to debug to be honest. Start using the developer tools and see what's going on. The form is hidden because of the `.collapse`.

[image: developer tools chrome]